# Decompress-zip emit anything in this Express route, why?

Tags: node.js, express, zip, serverless-framework, aws-serverless

Maybe I'm just tired but I can't figure out why this won't work! This is an express route running on AWS Lambda using the serverless framework (serverless-http).

I'm using Multer to handle the file upload and that seems to be working fine, I can see the file is uploaded and available. I'm deriving most of the file path from the req.file property that multer created. This code doesn't console.log anything in my cloudwatch logs, no error, no extraction complete, no "IN HERE!!" from the filter on unzipper.extract(). I've tested with fs.exists to ensure the file does actually exist (it does), and when I intentionally use a fake filename the error is accurately emitted. What's going on?

```
app.post('/incoming', upload.single('file'), (req, res) => {
  let filePath = '/tmp/'+req.file.filename
  let unzipper = new DecompressZip(filePath)
  unzipper.extract({
    path: '/tmp',
    filter: function (file) {
      console.log('IN HERE!!');
        return file.type !== "SymbolicLink";
    }
  })

  unzipper.on('error', err => {
    console.log('Error :', err);
    res.send('Error!' + err)
  })

  unzipper.on('extract', (log) => {
    console.log('Extract Completed.', log);
    let list = []
    const directoryPath = req.file.destination;
    console.log('directoryPath :', directoryPath);
    fs.readdir(directoryPath, function (err, files) {
      if (err) {
        console.log('Unable to scan directory: ' + err);
        return list.push(err)
      }
      files.forEach(function (file) {
        console.log(file);
        list.push(file)
      });
      res.send(list)
    });
  })
})
```